# How do I write a Flyway repeatable java-based migration?

Tags: java, flyway

I am using Flyway to try and write a repeatable Java based migration, using my own class names. i.e not follow the R__ class name pattern. My work place has a check style policy that does not allow underscores in class names.

The flyway documentation states that I can have more control over my class names by implementing MigrationInfoProvider. If I implement this interface, Flyway thinks I am doing a Versioned Migration, and I want to do a Repeatable Migration.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing MigrationInfoProvider, getVersion() needs to return null.

```
@Override
public MigrationVersion getVersion() {
    //will act as a repeatable migration
    return null;

}
```